# Umbraco: Custom Examine index with AWS flexible load balancing on EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, umbraco7, examine

Does anyone have an example of how to get this working?

I have a **custom indexer**, configured in `ExamineSettings.config` like this:

```
<add name="KeywordsIndexer"
           type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.SimpleDataIndexer, Examine"
           dataService="SearchIndexers.ParagraphKeywordIndexer"
           directoryFactory="Examine.LuceneEngine.Directories.TempEnvDirectoryFactory,Examine"
           indexTypes="KeywordIndexItem"/>
```

a **search provider**

```
<add name="KeywordsSearcher"
           indexSet="KeywordsIndexSet"
           enableLeadingWildcards="true"
           type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net" />
```

and an **index set**, in `ExamineIndex.config`

```
<IndexSet SetName="KeywordsIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Keywords/" IndexParentId="1119">
    <IndexUserFields>
      <add Name="ParagraphId" />
      <add Name="ArticleId" />
      <add Name="ChapterId" />
      <add Name="Keywords1" />
      <add Name="Keywords2" />
      <add Name="Keywords3" />
      <add Name="Keywords4" />
      <add Name="Keywords5" />
      <add Name="Keywords6" />
      <add Name="Keywords7" />
      <add Name="Keywords8" />
      <add Name="Keywords9" />
      <add Name="Keywords10" />
    </IndexUserFields>
  </IndexSet>
```

I then have a custom class which implements `ISimpleDataService` to query the content and create custom items which are inserted into the Index.

This all works fine when generating the index manually through the back-end *Rebuild Index* button, but I have no idea how to get this to propagate from the master machine to the slave machines (1 master, 1 slave at the moment in this setup https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/run-umbraco-cms-with-flexible-load-balancing-on-aws/).

I believe I have two questions:

**1) How can I get the index to automatically rebuild when content is published on the master server? (ideally only content within a specific parent/of a specific type)**

**2) Once rebuilt, how can I get the index to propagate to the slave machines so that the newly-rebuilt index is updated on all of them?**

The [docs](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible) are all Azure-specific so it's difficult to tell what is necessary and what isn't for AWS EBS. I've seen a few references to *"it just works"*, but unfortunately that's definitely not the case in my experience so far!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.